# how to check if uploaded file is php?

Tags: php, file-upload

I programmed a file upload script and i want to check if uploaded file is PHP.

I want secure my script so the unique files allowed to be uploaded are CSS and XML.

This is my code:

```
<form action="cp_home.php?mode=up_styles&type=uploading" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
     <input class="fixed" name="ufile" type="file" id="ufile" size="35" />
     <input type="button" name="Submit" onclick="upload()" value="up style" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check for extension since only php extension files will be executed by php.

```
$info = pathinfo(basename($_FILES['image']['name']));
$ext = strtolower($info['extension']);

if ($ext != 'php') {
    // process file upload
}
```

or if you server support for php3 or php5 file extensions you may want to use

```
if (!preg_match('/^php/', $ext)) {
    // process file upload
}
```

Comment: Note that if Apache's MultiViews feature is enabled it will look at all extensions and will execute (for example) `foo.php.en` as PHP.

Answer (score 0):

In your php code check for extension :

```
$allowedExts = array("css", "xml"); // css and xml are allowed here, if you want more add it here.
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));

if(in_array($extension, $allowedExts)){

   // your code here

}
```

Comment: Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference

Comment: can anyone change shell name to `shell.php.css` and upload it the shell will work

Comment: @user2036850 no only files with php extension will be executed by php.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $allowedExts = array("css", "xml");
        $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));

        if (in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {

            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']["tmp_name"], PATH.$name)) {

                if (file_exists($name . $extension)) {
                    echo "uploaded";
                }
                else{
                    echo "not";
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to check it

1.You can check it javascript itself

```
function is_php(filename){
return filename.split('.').pop()=="php";
}
```

2.Or else you can simply check in the backend .. For example if you use php itself then use the following code

```
$path_parts = pathinfo($filename);
if($path_parts['extension']!="php")
return false;
else 
return true;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var x = "1.txt";
alert (x.substring(x.lastindexOf(".")+1));
```

Use this on the input form file text.